# MFC versions for visual studio

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, version

what is the version of MFC in VC++ 6.0,vc++ 2003,vc++ 2005 and vc++ 2008 ?
i faced this question in interview but i could not reply?
so any body tell me the versions of MFC.

Comment: That is the worse interview question ever.

Answer (score 8):

[See this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library#Versions). Specifically:

```
VC++ 6.0   MFC 6.0        (mfc42.dll)
VC++ 2003  MFC 7.1        (mfc71.dll), .NET 1.1
VC++ 2005  MFC 8.0        (mfc80.dll), .NET 2.0
VC++ 2008  MFC 9.0.21022  (mfc90.dll), .NET 3.5
```

Answer (score -1):

MFC have at least four generation in the pass 10 years,We can see ,the main difference between the generations is the development of the compiler of C++ class type .What i intersted in is why you ask this question?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's given in the question itself: read `i faced this question in interview but i could not reply`.